# How to make sysctl network bridge settings persist after a reboot?

Tags: 12.04, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, nat

I am setting up a notebook for software demo purpose.  The machine has 8GB RAM, a Core i7 Intel CPU, a 128GB SSD, and runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. The notebook is used as a KVM host and runs a few KVM guests.

All such guests use the `virbr0` default bridge. To enable them to communicate with each other using multicast, I added the following to the host's `/etc/sysctl.conf`, as shown below

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Afterwards, following `man sysctl(8)`, I issued the following:

```
sudo /sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

My understanding is that this should make these settings persist over reboots.  I tested it, and was surprised to find out the following:

```
root@sdn1 :/proc/sys/net/bridge# more *tables
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-arptables
::::::::::::::
1
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
::::::::::::::
1
::::::::::::::
bridge-nf-call-iptables
::::::::::::::
1
```

All defaults are coming back!

Yes. I can use some kludgy "get arounds" such as putting a `/sbin/sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` into the host's `/etc/rc.local` but I would rather "do it right".  Did I misunderstand the man page or is there something that I missed?

Thanks for any hints.

-- Zack

Answer (score 1):

By serendipity, I ran into some additional info.  Even the "kludgy get around" I first thought about is a "suggested solution" in the [Debain wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Setting_up_bridge-related_kernel_variables), it doesn't work on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine! Sigh :-(

Please see [Some sysctl's are ignored on boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/50093)  - someone reported this bug back in 2006 and it's still not fixed!

Note that [Setting up bridge-related kernel variables](http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Setting_up_bridge-related_kernel_variables) is also referenced in the 2nd link above.

A rather disappointing situation, IMHO.

-- Zack

Answer (score 0):

Still hit this issue on my Debian Jessie installation. I've written the systemd script below as workaround. Note that it will be executed later that the sysctl configs would have been read, but that is no issue in my case.

```
[Unit]
Description=Bridge configuration
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root
User=root
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Don't forget to enable it with `systemctl enable bridge-config.service`.